# how can we upload, update and even remove certifications by **REST API**?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Hi I have one question App registration certification part, how can we upload, update and even remove certifications by **REST API**?
I had found one api named "addKey" in graph API, but not sure whether it is what I need since I had tried to use postman to send request, but response replied invalid audience, but my token had included it... any idea?

[postman details for addKey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rikq.png)

[access token request details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4LX4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have already found the solution.
the key is to invoke the rest API by patch, and the URL is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{your object id}
```

This one needs one token, and the token generator needs to contains the resource `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` that represents graph API.
and dont forget to make configuration in APP registration.

Here is my current API permission list. It works for me.

[image]